# Draw a border and shadow onto a UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have been able to redraw a UIImage with a border successfully, but not with a border + shadow. The code below successfully draws the image with a white border, but I cannot figure out how to include a drop shadow under the border. Help is greatly appreciated!

```
- (UIImage *)generatePhotoFrameWithImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width + 50, image.size.height + 60);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(25, 35, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [image drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(context, CGRectMake(25, 35, image.size.width, image.size.height), 50);
    
    //CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, -60), 5, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    
    UIImage *result =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}
```

PS:  I am not using a UIImageView because I need to preserve the full image quality.

Comment: In what way does `UIImageView` lose image quality?

Comment: I needed to be able to output the image to a file after I applied the shadow/border. You can render a UIImageView out to PNG/BMP but they only come out the size of the UIImageView.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call `CGContextSetShadowWithColor` before you stroke the border, so the border will cast a shadow.

If you don't want the border to cast a shadow onto the image, you need to set up a transparency layer in which you draw both the image and the border.  You can read about transparency layers in the [*Quartz 2D Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_trans_layers/dq_trans_layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH210-TPXREF101).

If you want to preserve image quality, you need to use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and pass in the scale of the original image.

```
- (UIImage *)generatePhotoFrameWithImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width + 50, image.size.height + 60);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(25, 35, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, image.scale); {
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, NULL); {
            [image drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 5), 5, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
            CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(context, CGRectMake(25, 35, image.size.width, image.size.height), 50);
        } CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context);
    }
    UIImage *result =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thank you Rob for pointing me the right direction. This is the final code which draws a white border around an image, and then a light grey shadow around the outside of the border

```
- (UIImage *)generatePhotoStackWithImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width + 70, image.size.height + 70);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(25, 25, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, image.scale); {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        //Shadow
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 0), 10, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.5f].CGColor);

        CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer (context, NULL);
        //Draw
        [image drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(context, rect, 40);
        CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context);
    }

    UIImage *result =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}
```